# How to sendFile in express using req.params and join method?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating routes in express.js using route parameters. I want a url `example.com/case/firstCase` with `firstCase` being a parameter.

However, I don't know how to use sendFile with `params`. What I'm trying to do is to append `.html` but I think it's not working since the method `join` add `/` between each element separated by comma. In other words, the path would be `views/statics/case/firstCase/.html`

Here is my code in server.js.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
// no need to use app.use(app.router) because of that update
// function signature express.static(root, [options])
app.use(express.static('public'));
// mount root to views/statics
app.use('/', express.static('views/statics'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT,() => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`)
  });

app.get('/case',(req,res,next)=> {
  res.sendFile('case.html', { root: path.join( __dirname, 'views/statics')})
})


app.get('/case/:case',(req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/statics/case', req.params.case + '.html'));
}))
```

Comment: You want to show `.html` extension ?

Comment: Would be even better if I can render the file without showing extension. However, I currently cannot render the file without extension yet.

Comment: what type of `view engine` are you using ?

Comment: oh so you need to use it to eliminate html extension? I didn't use it now.

Answer (score 0):

As above discussion your are not use `view engine`.

Add `view engine` like

1. Pug [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug)
2. Ejs [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs)